# Moving from Rackspace cloud files to Amazon S3

Tags: assets, amazon

Recently moved server from Rackspace to AWS. A lot of media in our entries is hosted by rackspace cloud servers. How intensive would it be to move these all to Amazon S3 in regards to linking media to entries?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not drag-n-dropping inside Craft. It might end up being very intense indeed, and break down in multiple ways.

A better way would be to download the media locally, replicating the folder structure and files in the S3 bucket, and then manually changing the source id of the Asset / Folders in question in the database.

For concurrent uploading, take a look at [s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd).